# Problems installing TensorFlow on Mac

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow to the installation guide on [tensorflow.org](http://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md) and have installed Python version 2 again for that reason using Homebrew.

When I run the installation as described

```
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

I get this error message:

```
tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, but have no idea. Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

I do not want to use virtualenv, since anaconda already comes with its own environment management `conda`. When installing the newest version 0.6.0 directly with pip install, I had a similar error. It seemed to not resolve the dependencies correctly.

Here is what you can try:

1. Install anaconda
2. Create a new conda workspace
3. Download the specific protobuf version that tensorflow needs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/3.0.0a3
4. Install it via `sudo easy_install ~/Downloads/protobuf-3.0.0a3-py2.7.egg`
5. Install a numpy version greater than 1.08.x via `conda install numpy`
6. Download the 0.6.0 version of tensorflow: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
7. Install via `pip install ~/Downloads/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl`

When you install tensorflow from the whl file directly, it should tell you when dependencies are not there. It seems not to be able to resolve these conflicts independently. My setup had issues with protobuf and numpy. After installing them manually everything worked fine.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a common issue. Try to install it in the virtualenv. Its a much better solution, as you can always easily set up a new version of tensorflow without conflicts.

VirutalEnv Tutorial:
http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.md#virtualenv-based_installation

Comment: FWIW, I never 'got' virtualenvs — and had this sort of problem with homebrew and various random Pythons on my machine — till I started using [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install). TensorFlow installed fine in a Python 2.7 `conda` environment.

Comment: Dunno why but many people on github seem to be complaining that tensorflow runs only in a virtualenv envoirment on their mac osx. I had this issue too and never used virtuelenv before, but Im amazed now by it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, I didn't have any problem installing tensorflow with the anaconda version of python: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

The anaconda version also provides science, math, engineering, and data analysis packages.  A lot of people on https://www.kaggle.com/ seem to use this...just a thought.