# Installing tensor flow on mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensor flow on my mac with

```
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

And I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/9y/r7zhtk2s1s90hwcty1d6964w0000gn/T/pip-pnXFjW-build/setup.py'
```

I am on OSX 10.11.1 and all the development tools, pip and python2.7 are installed.

Comment: For some reason, TensorFlow seems to install best in a virtual environment. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870404/problems-installing-tensorflow-on-mac?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730259/tensorflow-installaion-error-on-mac?rq=1) for example. If you're unused to virtualenvs, I recommend using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Comment: Thanks. I installed it using anaconda now

Comment: You should make the comment about using anaconda an answer. People don't always look into the comments for answers.

Comment: How did you use anaconda to install it? I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: @Adam_G I used the wheel file provided. For example, after installing anaconda, run: conda install --name ml -c https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl This, for example, installs tensorflow 0.5.0 in my 'ml' conda environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly the solution you're looking for, but I personally spent the last two hours diagnosing a similar issue where TensorFlow wouldn't work after correctly installing and having its packages satisfied.

It was throwing one of the strange _IO module import errors that seemed to be saying python was working correctly, and I ended up tracing it back all the way to the System Integrity Protection issue introduced in El Cap.

See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) for easy fix that will let pip work correctly again.

> For those that are curious, Apple introduced SIP to make sure no user accidentally hurts system files, but in the process it makes it trickier for users to run commands as root

Also, remember to run

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
```

and

```
sudo pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.5.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

After disabling SIP to make sure you patch up any requirements.  You may need to uninstall some pip packages if this fails for some reason.

As a final note, you should be off the ground if, in the python shell, you can

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and it doesn't throw any errors.

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow)[elcapitan](/questions/tagged/elcapitan)